How to pass a global environment variable set during docker run command into a react app?
I am trying to run a container on my image.
The container run command I am using is:
docker run -e REACT_APP_BACKEND_WEBSERVICE="http://webservice-backend:8080" -p 3000:3000 username/webservicename

Then in my react code, I am trying to access it at the runtime using
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_WEBSERVICE);

But in my console it is printing undefined.
I dont want to pass the env variable from the dockerfile itself.

Since the environment variables is actually added staticallly during the build phase of the react application this will not work. You could you a solution like https://github.com/codegowhere/react-inject-env in order to inject variables from the current environment into you application. This would then allow you to change the environment variable runtime e.g. docker run -e REACT_APP_BACKEND_WEBSERVICE="http://webservice-backend:8080" -p 3000:3000 username/webservicename

when you are passing env variable REACT_APP_BACKEND_WEBSERVICE while you run the contaner, its available to the container but the catch is react app needs the variable duing the build not after its built.
so when you only pass it during the run i dont think its going to work,
instead what you can do is pass the env variable while you are building the image so that react app gets built with the appropirate env varaible
first method(passing env variables in docker build command):
docker build --build-arg REACT_APP_BACKEND_WEBSERVICE="http://webservice-backend:8080" -t username/webservicename .


and then run the container normally
docker run -p 3000:3000 username/webservicename


second method():

create .env file in the same directory level as Dockerfile and save your env varaible there.
add this to your Dockerfile, before build command is run

COPY .env .env

this is for failsafe, usually docker copies everything in same direcotry level when you do 'COPY . .'
3.make sure your react app can load the env varaibles from .env file during build command is run, you can make use of react-dotenv package.

now just build the docker image

docker build -t username/webservicename .


run it

docker run -p 3000:3000 username/webservicename

There are many ways to achieve the solution but this should solve your problem for now. Its better to look into contens how micro frontends ENV works and how ENV are managed in docker containers.

The answer nicely pinpoints the issue! Please not that your proposed solution assumes that the build phase is made in a Docker container as well. It could very well be built locally, then the production build could be bundled into a container.

I want to pass that variable during runtime, and not when I build my image.

@Fakipo its possible to do that but i will take custom configuration, as i mentioned in my answer, react app is not designed to make use of env varaibles after it is already built. you can try  building the app with one env varaible and run in your local, now what you are asking is you want to change the env varaible value that you set during build in the running app. what will you do in that situation??  you will update the env varaible and rebuild it , what you are saying to do is something similar to this. passing  env in docker run is somewhat similar to this.
